# vba/catvba class instantiation

Tags: vba, catia

i want to declare class globaly
here is my example:

i want to use class clsIEError that looks exactly like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub m(msg As String, Optional title As String = "Title:")

    'Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0

    'this method will be used as defualt method
    'and here are attributes msg and title used to create some inteface
End Sub
```

and this is how it works example1:

```
Sub CATMain()

     Dim ie As clsIEError
     Set ie = New clsIEError

     ie "test", "title"

     Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

but my problem is that i want to have it globally example2:

```
Option Explicit

Public ie As clsIEError

Private Function Init()
    Set ie = New clsIEError
End Function

Sub CATMain()
    Call Init

'   and to use it same as in example 1    
    ie "test", "title" 

'   but i am able to use it only like:
'   ie.m "test", "title" 'works as expected 

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

why with public default method doesnt work?

Comment: Why are `classes` created in the first place in general?

Comment: I think is not important, but in this case i have some custom user interface that i want to use in different modules.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you really want to use?

Comment: instead of ' ie.m "test", "title" ' i want to use it as ' ie "test", "title" ', with public declaration, that's all

Comment: i don't know about the catia VBA editor, but in case you're doing this in MS office or Catia is similar, you cannot provided the attributes simply in code - you unfortunately need to export the class, edit the text document with the Attribute line and then import it back (where the line is hidden in the editor) - see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx Though I agree that then example one should not work either... :-/

Comment: you are right it is not possible to provide attribute directly in vba editor, i know that as well :) i did followed this procedure from cpearson as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this doesn't work just as you describe.  I get "Expected procedure, not variable" at run-time, but no compile errors.  It must be a bug in the VB parser, but that's the only explanation I can come up with.

I always thought that the attribute had to match the element name.  Where you have

```
Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
```

I thought you should have

```
Attribute m.VB_UserMemId = 0
```

But it seems to work (with the locally declared variable) either way.  It's a terrible answer, but the answer is to explicitly call the method.  Sorry.

Comment: Hi Dick, thank you for your answer. Attribute element name will be automatically changed to pass to element name. If you change a name of element, or even type of it, vba editor will adjust it automaticaly. in fact, it doesnt have to work globally, but i would like to use this object at least on module/class module level.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it will answer your question explicitly, but, as for me I wanted to create an instance of a class that would be accessible throughout my project. Basically I needed to create Static Class or Singleton. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196960/1866635) that was quite useful.